# Convert cURL multi-line output to single, semi-colon-separated line

Tags: curl

I'm using `curl -s -I -L example.com | grep 'HTTP\|Location'` to track re-directs of a given URL which gives multi-line output.

```
$ curl -s -I -L google.com | grep 'HTTP\|Location'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I want to concatenate each line of the output and separate it with a semi-colon.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently;Location: http://www.google.com/;HTTP/1.1 200 OK;
```

I've tried `curl -s -I -L google.com | grep 'HTTP\|Location' | tr '\n' ';' > file` but this only replaces `\n` with `;` and doesn't concatenate the lines.

```
$ curl -s -I -L google.com | grep 'HTTP\|Location' | tr '\n' ';' > file    
$ cat file
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently;
Location: http://www.google.com/;
HTTP/1.1 200 OK;
```

Would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol requires that header lines end with CR LF (`\r\n`); you must delete one of them and translate the other to a newline:

```
$ curl -s -I -L google.com | grep 'HTTP\|Location' | tr -d '\r' | tr '\n' ';'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found;Location: http://www.google.eu/?gws_rd=cr&ei=Hx1JWIDpGordvATO65S4BQ;HTTP/1.1 200 OK;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `-w` argument for `curl`:

```
> curl -fs -w "%{response_code},%{redirect_url}\n" -o /dev/null http://google.com
302,http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=...
```